# Spark with IntelliJ or Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I am trying to setup IntelliJ for spark 2.11 but it is very daunting and after days I have not been able to compile a simple instruction such as with "spark.read.format" which is not found in main core and sql spark libraries.

I have seen a few posts on the subject but with none resolved. Does anyone have some experience with perhaps a working sample program I can start with?

Could it be that it would be easier with Eclipse?

Many thanks in advance for your answers,
EZ

Comment: This question interest me too. I hope some one can share his experience Spark with IntelliJ vs Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

build project in Intellij using with scala 2.11 and sbt 0.13: then ensure that your `plugins.sbt` contains as below:

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.13.0")
```

then your `build.sbt` must contain as below:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val sparkVersion = "2.1.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion %"provided"

libraryDependencies +=  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion %"provided"
```

Then write your code, click `Terminal` in `Intellij` and type `sbt assembly`: you can ship that jar to remote cluster, otherwise run from `Intelij` locally, let me know how it goes